# how to store API data in local storage JavaScript and use it again or assign it to another variable

Tags: javascript, json, api, async-await

```
const data = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
};
```

I have been trying to access data here, and I have searched the net, and as a beginner, the answers I'm getting are too confusing, so please make it simple for me. Thank you.

Comment: In the interest of content quality, duplicative questions are not permitted here. Please research your inquiry before posting here in accordance with [ask]. This is a duplicate of [How to Store Objects in HTML5 localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score -2):

When you get your data, you can store it in localStorage. Like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("someData", data);
```

and after that, you can use it anywhere when you get it from localStorage with this:

```
const someData = localStorage.getItem("someData");
```

And if you want to clear this data, you can use this:

```
localStorage.removeItem("someData);
```

EDIT:
localStorage only supports strings! For arrays in JSON format, You can use ***JSON.stringify()*** and ***JSON.parse().***

```
var data= [];
data[0] = prompt("New data?");
localStorage.setItem("someData", JSON.stringify(data));

And when u get it, you can use this one:
//...
var someData= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("someData"))
```

Comment: This will only work if data is a string but that is not what is indicated in the question

Comment: Sorry, I miss that. I edit my answer, you can look it

Comment: Right but you made no mention of using JSON methods in the answer which means it would not work as shown there